# What does owning side really mean?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

**Problem:** Seems I don't properly understand logic of Hibernate *-to-many mapping, or to be precise owning side.

**Example (one-to-many where one is owning side)**

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why I should duplicate the physical information? And why `Troop` table doesn't contains `troop_fk` field (look at example above)
2. Does Hibernate ignore all the queries on mapped (not owner) side?
3. Does owner side implies some restrictions on the order in which entites should be saved?
4. What does the next phrase mean?

> Mapping one end of an association with inverse="true" does not affect
>   the operation of cascades as these are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: This is JPA, not Hibernate specifically. That will make googling for information yield more results. If this is a one to many mapping I'd expect the @OneToMany side to define a mappedBy attribute and not a join column.

Comment: @Gimby there are many situations. I take that example from Hibernate docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I should duplicate the physical information? And why Troop table
>   doesn't contains troop_fk field (look at example above)

Between two entities you can have multiple relationships, like:  Organisation has multiple employees, and Organisation is lead by multiple employees.  Only if a relationship is bilateral you can speak about owning and non-owning side. Suppose that both relationships are bilateral, meaning that every entity has two fields each. Now it would be unclear for Hibernate to map those fields to two relationship. This is why this notion was introduced, to pair/assign the fields to the same relationhip.

Example:

```
public class Organisation {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employeeOf")
    private List<Employee> employees;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="leaderOf")
    private List<Employee> leaders;
}

public class Employee {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("organisationAsEmployee_id")
    private Organisation employeeOf;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("organisationAsLeader_id")
    private Organisation leaderOf;
}
```

Suppose in `Organisation.employees` you wouldn't have `mappedBy`. Then Hibernate wouldn't know whether this field is in the same relationship with Employee.employeeOf or Employee.leaderOf or a single independent relationship (with no matching field in the Employee entity). *And if it does not know that piece of information, it does not know how to join the tables, for example, or whether it has to create a new field or not.*

> Does Hibernate ignore all the queries on mapped (not owner) side?

Hibernate (JPA) ignores the @JoinColumn of the NOT-owner side, but not the cascading annotations. And a NOT-owner side MUST have a `mappedBy` property in the ManyToOne annotation (which you do not have => you do not have a bilateral relationship right now).

> Does owner side implies some restrictions on the order in which
>   entites should be saved?

No.

Comment: can you provide an example for the first point please? And about the second: does it mean just that not-owner side hasn't cascades?

Comment: Answered both of your questions in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below is my general understanding of this concept. I don't know
if this corresponds 100% to `Hibernate`'s or `JPA`'s usage of it.

When you have aggregation you have an entity (say `Car`) and it has a collections of entities of another type (say `Seat`). Or you have a `Student` and it has a collection of `Course` entities (the courses he has enrolled in).

Now this collection may be owned or not owned.

1. When it's owned it means it belong to this parent only, the parent owns it. It is a modeling concept. For example, if you delete the parent, then the child entities should not exist too anymore, they just don't make sense outside of the owning entity. So they should be deleted too. Not sure if this `Car` and `Seat` is the best example of an owned collection, as these `Seat` entities may be theoretically moved to another `Car` instance (say in a repair store).
2. On the other hand you may have a collection which is not owned. Say a `Student` has a collection of `Course`s it has enrolled in. Now, the `Student` does not own this collection because apparently if the `Student` leaves the university (so we delete him), that does not mean that his `Course`s cease to exist. I realize this is a many to many example. I can't think of a good one to many example right now of a collection which is not owned.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk I don't know their answers.